# How to prevent click on raycasted object during mousemove?

Tags: javascript, three.js, click, preventdefault

I have a group of clickable objects that can be spun either using the scroll wheel or by clicking and dragging. The problem I am having is when you drag and then release on top of an object, it will launch the click animation.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/jacob_truax/j4okp5c6/) is a link to a fiddle of the simplified project.

Does anyone know how to stop the click from being recorded during the drag? It seems like its being a bit more difficult because they are raycasted objects.

My js functions:

```
document.addEventListener("mousedown", function () {
    isMouseDown = true
    startX = event.pageX
    startY = event.pageY
    document.body.style.cursor = 'grabbing';
  })

  document.addEventListener("mouseup", function () {
    isMouseDown = false
    document.body.style.cursor = 'grab';
  })

  document.addEventListener("mousemove", function (event) {
    if (isMouseDown) {
      document.body.style.cursor = 'grabbing'
    }

    aimX = ((window.innerWidth / 2) - event.pageX) * 0.35
    aimY = ((window.innerHeight / 2) - event.pageY) * 0.5

    mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;

    raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera)

    const intersections = raycaster.intersectObjects(group.children)

    if (intersections.length > 0) {
      if(projectHov){
        if (INTERSECTED != intersections[0].object) {
            if (INTERSECTED)
            INTERSECTED.material.color.setHex(INTERSECTED.currentHex);
            INTERSECTED = intersections[0].object;
            INTERSECTED.currentHex = INTERSECTED.material.color.getHex();
            //setting up new material on hover
            INTERSECTED.material.color.setHex( 0xadadad );
            if (INTERSECTED){
              if(projectHov){
                document.body.style.cursor = "pointer"
              }
            }
        }
      }

      } else {
          if (INTERSECTED) INTERSECTED.material.color.setHex(INTERSECTED.currentHex);
          document.body.style.cursor = "grab";
          INTERSECTED = null;
      }

// Moving the objects ==========================
    if(isMouseDown) {
      let currentRotation = new THREE.Matrix4();
              currentRotation.makeRotationFromEuler(group.rotation);

              let newEuler = new THREE.Euler(0, ((event.pageX - startX) + (event.pageY - startY)) / 325, 0);
              let newRotation = new THREE.Matrix4();
              newRotation.makeRotationFromEuler(newEuler);

              let finalRotation = new THREE.Matrix4();
              finalRotation.multiplyMatrices(newRotation, currentRotation);

              group.rotation.setFromRotationMatrix(finalRotation);

              startX = event.pageX;
              startY = event.pageY;
    }
  })
section.addEventListener('click', onDocumentMouseDown, false);

  function onDocumentMouseDown(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
      mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
      raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
      const intersections = raycaster.intersectObjects(objects)

// Animation =================================
          if (intersections.length > 0){
            if(projectHov){
              tl.play();

              tl.to(backTag, 1, {
                delay: 1.25,
                autoAlpha:1,
              }, 0);

            }

// Animation ===================================
            if (intersections[0].object == old ) {
              if(projectHov){
                tlOld.play();
                projectHov = false
                tlOld.to(old, 1.5, {three:{scaleX: 1.5, scaleY: 1.5, x:0, y:0, z:0}, ease:Power2.easeInOut}, 0);
                tlOld.to(fnup, 1, {three:{y:-4000, opacity: 0 }, ease:Power2.easeInOut}, 0);
                tlOld.to(alex, 1, {three:{y:-4000, opacity: 0 }, ease:Power2.easeInOut}, 0);
                tlOld.to(cam, 1, {three:{y:-4000, opacity: 0 }, ease:Power2.easeInOut}, 0);
                tlOld.to(mirrorCube, 1, {three:{y:-400, opacity: 0 }, ease:Power2.easeInOut}, 0);
              groupRotate = false
            }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to store `intersections[0].object.uuid;` in a variable and update it on mousedown and mouseup. Then compare stored uuid with raycasted object uuid on mouse up. Process further only if they are equal.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with uuid's. Is there a certain way I need to hold the variable? Could you please be a bit more specific?

Comment: Ah ok I see what you mean, but I am having trouble storing the uuid in order to compare it to the raycasted object uuid. Thanks for that, didn't realize uuid was something I could use as data with three.js objects.